# compare results with another table in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables...

```
Table1:
ID, Name, Country
Table2:
ID, accountID, parent

table1.id = table2.acountID
```

My script does a search for all records with a particular parent.
I want to compare those results with table1 and return all entries that wern't in the search.

eg.
Table1:

```
1, Bill, AU
2, Charles, US
3, Clare, CA
```

Table2:

```
1, 1, Mary
2, 1, William
3, 2, Henry
```

Search (select * from table2 WHERE accountID='1') returns:

```
1, 1, Mary
2, 1, William
```

and I want to get this results (from table1):

```
2, Charles, US
3, Clare, CA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID NOT IN
  (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE accountID = '1')
```

Comment: perfect! (or atleast it looks perfect). I assume it is cause it reads how I want it to :)

Answer (score 0):

Your search is returning all rows in Table2 where accountID = 1

To return all rows that were not returned in the search, you would find all rows in Table1 which have an ID other than 1, or do not have any matching rows in Table2.

```
SELECT
  ID
FROM
  Table1
WHERE
  ID <> 1
  OR NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE accountID = 1)
```

Seems simple?